# IAR Workbench Error [Li005] while copying files between examples

Tags: c, linker, embedded, cypress, iar

I'm having the following errors:

> Error[Li005]: no definition for "Mfs_Uart_Init" [referenced from C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded
>       Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
>       Debug\Obj\main.o]
>
> Error[Li005]: no definition for "Mfs_Uart_Write" [referenced from C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded
>       Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
>       Debug\Obj\main.o]
>
> Error[Li005]: no definition for "Mfs_Uart_Read" [referenced from C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded
>       Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
>       Debug\Obj\main.o]

I'm trying to "merge/combine" the ADC and UART examples for Cypress s6j3200

Using Windows 10, IAR Arm 8.50.1

**Build log:**

```
Building configuration: single_irq_sw - TCFLASH Debug

Updating build tree...


Linking
ilinkarm.exe C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\
S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\adc12b.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR 
Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\
TCFLASH Debug\Obj\exceptions.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\
8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\flash_marker.o C:\
Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\
examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\interrupts.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded 
Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
Debug\Obj\main.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\
s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\mfs_uart.o C:\Users\rcorder1\
Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\
single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\pdl.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\
arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\port.o C:\Users\
rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\
adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\start.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\
GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\
startup.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\
S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\Obj\sysctrl.o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR 
Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\
TCFLASH Debug\Obj\Traveo_template_version.o --no_out_extension -o C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR 
Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\
TCFLASH Debug\Exe\single_irq_sw.out --redirect _Printf=_PrintfFullNoMb
--redirect _Scanf=_ScanfFullNoMb --map 
C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\
examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH Debug\List\single_irq_sw.map
--config C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR 
Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.4\arm\config\linker\Cypress\s6j33xDx.icf
--semihosting --entry 

__iar_program_start --vfe --text_out locale


   IAR ELF Linker V8.50.1.245/W32 for ARM

   Copyright 2007-2020 IAR Systems AB.

Error[Li005]: no definition for "Mfs_Uart_Init" [referenced from C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded 
Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
Debug\Obj\main.o]

Error[Li005]: no definition for "Mfs_Uart_Write" [referenced from C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded 
Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
Debug\Obj\main.o]

Error[Li005]: no definition for "Mfs_Uart_Read" [referenced from C:\Users\rcorder1\Documents\IAR Embedded 
Workbench\GPIO & ADC\arm\8.50.1\Cypress\s6j3200\S6J3260Evl\examples\adc12b\single_irq_sw\TCFLASH
Debug\Obj\main.o]


  8'058 bytes of readonly  code memory
  1'214 bytes of readonly  data memory
  3'390 bytes of readwrite data memory


Errors: 3
Warnings: none


Link time:   0.08 (CPU)   0.06 (elapsed)
Error while running Linker


Total number of errors: 3
Total number of warnings: 0


Build failed.
```

Comment: ask IAR or Cypress support.

Comment: It is a linker error - you have failed to link the object code to library containing `Mfs_Uart_Init`.  Probably you have not added the source to the project. Few is any are going to risk downloading your zip archive.  The information must be included in the question.  A copy & paste of the build log text from a _clean_ build or _rebuild all_ will probably be sufficient to identify the problem.  It will show everything that is being compiled and linked, and thus what is missing.

Comment: thanks, i will update the question and try what you suggest

Comment: @RobertoCordero sorry, my comment should have read "_... the object code *or* library...._".

Comment: @Clifford question edited, included build log

Comment: The update shows only the linker invocation, not the compilation.  Nonetheless it includes mfs_uart.o which I suppose is where you expect these missing symbols to reside?  Possibilities include: 1) you used a mix C++ and C compilation and the symbols have C++ linkage but main is using C linkage, 2) they are call-backs that you are expected to provide, 3) the source has conditional compilation that was not met causing the symbols to be omitted.

Comment: I am not going to get into an edit war now you've rolled it back twice, but suggest that the error messages are easier to read in a mono-spaced font and that quite markup is inappropriate.  As it happens the messages are repeated in teh build log so probably unnecessary.  It is of course possible to "quote" text in code mark-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to check pdl_user.h file and make sure that it has the following:

```
#define PDL_PERIPHERAL_ENABLE_ADC12B  PDL_ON
#define PDL_PERIPHERAL_ENABLE_SYSCTRL PDL_ON
#define PDL_PERIPHERAL_ENABLE_UART0   PDL_ON
#define PDL_PERIPHERAL_ENABLE_PORT    PDL_ON
```

Comment: Posibility no. 3 then?  You should accept your own answer I suggest.